# using laravel option from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

in controller I do this

```
$actions = array('' => 'Select Action Name') + Action::lists('name' , 'id');
```

I want to use that `$actions` variable in my javascript.

I tried these ways:

```
<script>
var actions = {{actions}};
</script>
```

but I got this excpetion

```
Array to string conversion
```

I also tried this:

```
<script>
    @foreach($actions as $action)
        console.log($action);
    @endforeach
</script>
```

but in the console I got this exception

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $action is not defined
```

could you help me please?

Comment: I wonder why you downvote the question. I tried hard to solve the problem and I showed you a good efforts.

Comment: +1 @AnastasieLaurent is right. Failing at your attempts is kind of the reason for posting a question. I think she's shown real effort here.

Comment: There is a nice package to help you pass easily data from Laravel to js [here](https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer). Have a look it deserves the effort. You can pass data at once by doing: `JavaScript::put(['foo' => 'bar']);` Now `var foo = 'bar';` is accessible to the window scope for your js inside `script` tags. A really clean solution.

Comment: @marios WOW fascinated ... Absolutely I will use it. Many Thanks

Comment: Thanks keep on the good job!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to echo it with curly braces:

```
<script>
    @foreach($actions as $id => $name)
        console.log('{{ $id }}', '{{{ $name }}}');
    @endforeach
</script>
```

Your other option is to use the array by converting it to JSON:

```
<script>
    var actions = {{ json_encode($actions) }};
</script>
```

Comment: Many thanks I got the result but for some reasons the result are not correct. each `$action` is a `name` and `id`, what I got is just the `name` . how can I take both of them please? +1

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent - The second example I've shown you should give you what you want.

Comment: I edited some of your code so the final code is this <script>
    var actions = {{ json_encode($actions) }};
    for (var key in actions){
        console.log(key, actions[key]);
    }
</script>`` and it works :) many thanks I will accept the answer when the system allows

Answer (score 1):

`$actions` is an array inside of your controller.  To pass it down to a view, you could do this inside of a route callback of a controller:

```
return View::make('someview')->with('actions', $actions);
```

Then you would be able to access the `$actions` variable, an array, from within your view.

However, there are some big differences between Javascript Arrays and PHP arrays.  Most likely, when you convert a PHP array to JavaScript you wind up with a JavaScript *object* instead, since arrays in javascript cannot have non-numeric indices.

What you probably want to do is `json_encode` your array in PHP, and then you can `JSON.parse` inside your JavaScript:

```
<script>
    var actions = {{ json_encode($actions) }};
    console.log(actions);
</script>
```

Comment: +1 to your efforts, but the other answer helped me first. Many thanks

Comment: You can only call `JSON.parse` on a string. Drop it since it doesn't work and there's no need for it.

Comment: From the manual, this is the function description: `string json_encode ( mixed $value [, int $options = 0 [, int $depth = 512 ]] )` If you don't want a string in the JavaScript variable, how do you get the data?

Comment: @watcher It returns a string, which you are then `echo`ing directly into the page. That string is then parsed in JS - *not as a string* - as regular JS code, so it ends up being an object automatically. Try it and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Joseph Silber gotcha, makes sense now.